# Where can I use the $K jquery in a KRL ruleset?

Tags: javascript, krl

I'm writing an app to try and modify a page using JavaScript and I'm having trouble figuring out where to put the JavaScript I want to run. I am using the KRL specific jQuery handle of $K.

- Where are all the places I can use JavaScript in my KRL ruleset/app?
- Do you have an example that demonstrates using JavaScript in each of these areas?

Comment: Wow, this questions looks familiar! :)

Comment: @Dustin, haha! Yes. Wasn't sure you were going to ask it so I asked it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to put javascript directly onto a webpage inside of a KRL ruleset. Through an emit block or an external resource. Let's discuss emit blocks first.

Emits can appear in the action block of a rule, or in a ruleset's global block. You can use an emit with either a [heredoc](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Here_Doc) or [clownhats](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Clown_hat), but clownhats are preferred.

Here's an example of emitting javascript in a rule:

```
rule emitter {
    select when web pageview "exampley.com"
    {
        emit <| 
            $K("body").append("Hello from a rule.");
        |>;
    }
}
```

Here's an example of emitting javascript in a global block:

```
global {
    emit <|
        $K("body").append("Hello from the global block.");
    |>;
}
```

The second way to place javascript on a page in KRL is to use an [external resource](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Use_resource).

I'm going to refer you to the linked docs for the specifics, but you include an external javascript resource in the meta block of your ruleset like so:

```
use javascript resource "url-to-resource"
```

Let's say I have the following is the content of a javascript file located at `my-personal-website.com/awesome.js`:

```
$K("body").append("Hello from an external resource.");
```

To use that in a ruleset:

```
meta {
   // normal meta stuff...
   use javascript resource "my-personal-website.com/awesome.js"
}
```

Here's a complete ruleset showing the 2 different ways to place javascript on a page in a KRL ruleset:

```
ruleset a369x151 {
    meta {
        name "fun-with-javascript"
        description <<
            fun-with-javascript
        >>
        author "AKO"
        logging on

        use javascript resource "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4917848/js/example-external-resource.js"
    }

    global {
        emit <|
            $K("body").append("<br/>Hello from the global block.");
        |>;
    }

    rule emitter {
        select when web pageview "exampley.com"
        {
            emit <| 
                $K("body").append("<br/>Hello from a rule.");
            |>;
        }
    }
}
```

Action shot after running app on [exampley.com](http://exampley.com/):
[image: exampley.com rocks!]

You can try it out yourself by getting the app bookmarklet [here](https://ako-random.s3.amazonaws.com/fun-with-javascript-so-question.html).